# How to hide the track on HSlider

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex-spark

Is there a way to hide the track in an HSlider and if possible so that only the button accepts mouse interaction?

I would like to layer two HSliders together on top of one another and make a pseudo multithumb slider and hide the track of one of them (so you can click the other thumb).

Comment: Have you tried track as visible = false? ex.:- hsliderID.track.visible = false;(on creationComplete of HSlider) where as hsliderID is ID of HSlider.

Comment: Or create a custom skin without track.

Comment: I tried slider.track.alpha = 0 and hid the track but I was not able to click anything behind it still.

Comment: Use visible, not alpha. Alpha just changes the transparency. Visible completely removes its viewable properties from the display list. Set visible to false and it will no longer accept mouse events and should allow you to click items under the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create custom skin for HSlider without track or with an invisible track